# Backing up encrypted /home/folder while on liveUSB

Tags: partitioning, backup, encryption

I am trying to backup to ehdd while on a liveUSB but when I write

```
$dd if=/dev/sda6 bs=8M | gzip -9 > /media/usb/backupimage.gz
```

I get the message "failed to open /dev/sda6':Permission denied (the /home/folder in there is encrypted).

What do I need to do?

I want to backup before resizing partitions with gparted before reinstalling system.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please edit your question and add more new information. How did you encrypt the home partition? Did you use cryptfs?

Comment: I was following [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: https://askubuntu.com/questions/603436/gparted-how-to-move-partition-to-extend-the-size

Comment: This was done many years ago in an earlier Ubuntu version around 2007 so I do not recall exactly what package did the encryption.

Comment: I am not sure the "permission denied" is because of the encrypted `/home/folder`. Please copy and paste the contents of the file `/etc/fstab` in your question. **Please edit the question and add new information up there.** format the pasted content as code, as you have done before with the `dd` command.

Comment: Please remember I have access only via terminal. No cut and paste for me....

Comment: You can highlight the text in terminal and press Ctrl+Shift+C to copy Right clicking the mouse button after highlighting will also give you the option to copy.

Comment: Have you tried the same command (you wrote in the question) with `sudo`?

Comment: Please write your own answer in the "Your Answer" window below. Later please accept your answer as the correct one, by placing the green check mark ✅ on its left margin. This will help others.