# 18.04 LTS boot fail after attempted upgrade to 20.04

Tags: boot, 18.04, updates, 20.04

I tried to upgrade my Lenovo Carbon X1 6th Generation laptop from 18.04 LTS to 20.04, but I encountered an error and it failed to upgrade. When I tried to boot after I had shut it down, it failed to boot and froze in the cryptsetup screen. I currently can't get onto my laptop due to this. Please help.

Comment: Did you back up your data? If so, do a clean reinstall

Comment: Unfortunately I did not.

Comment: Boot from a LiveUSB, then back up your data, then do a clean reinstall.

Comment: @user535733 My system is encrypted, will that still work?

Comment: Yes, but the data backup is more complex and tedious due to the encryption. Depends upon how you set up the encryption. How to backup an encrypted system has been asked and answered here before: Try the Search box at the top of the page.

Comment: I set it up when I installed Ubuntu, can you point me to a guide on how to do this?

Comment: Maybe this might help (or a similar guide -- google will be your friend!) : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1128136/backing-up-encrypted-home-folder-while-on-liveusb. ALWAYS backup your data going forward